# Censorship of Nudity in Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one

Certain cloud storage facilities have declared an absolute ban on the storage of images portraying nudity. This has implications for those involved in many fields, including naturism - a lawful pastime practised throughout Europe and the Americas.

Does Ubuntu One have any specific policy restricting the storage of images portraying nudity?

Answer (score 4):

I don't see anything in the [terms of service](https://one.ubuntu.com/terms/) that forbid it, as long as it is legal in your country/jurisdiction.

> **Acceptable use and conduct**
>
> All usage of the services must be legal
> and not infringe any third party's rights. You must not take any
> action or use the services in any way that might bring Canonical into
> disrepute, affect the ability of Canonical to provide the services, be
> illegal, or encourage illegal activities. You may not use the services
> in any manner that might be libellous or defamatory ([more info on what
> that means](https://www.eff.org/issues/bloggers/legal/liability/defamation)), that contains threats or incites violence towards
> individuals or entities, or that violates the privacy or publicity
> rights of any third party. Some services have usage limitations as
> indicated at https://one.ubuntu.com/plans, and you may not exceed
> these. As part of the services, you may store data on Canonical's
> servers or those of Canonical's suppliers. You should ensure that this
> data is not in breach of any applicable law and does not breach any
> individual's data protection or privacy rights. You shall indemnify
> Canonical in full for any loss, cost or damages suffered by it as a
> result of your use or misuse of the services.